# Storing kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail for an address book contact

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook, abperson

I'm trying to store the thumbnail for a contact in the address book.

The following allows me to retrieve both the thumbnail and the full image:

```
ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactRef, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);
(NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactRef, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
```

And this allows me to store the full image:

```
ABPersonSetImageData(contactRef, (__bridge CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage), nil);
```

But I cannot figure out how to store the thumbnail. There doesn't seem to be a method that takes `kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail` as a parameter to store the image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to get into the habit of answering my own questions.
After extensive research and going through Apple's API, I finally used a TSI to send a question to Apple with this specific situation. Their reply was this:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our
>   engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is
>   no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the
>   currently shipping system configurations.

So unfortunately, at this time in any case, this is not possible.